# Query Builder number format codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, format

I am trying to display the total price in jtable using format concat & number format, like:

Rp 1.000.000

but i got an error

```
<div id="container">
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as JUMLAH
FROM (`retribusi`)' at line 1</p><p>SELECT `ID_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI`, `NAMA_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI`, `TANGGAL`, CONCAT('Rp ', FORMAT(JUMLAH, `0))` as JUMLAH
FROM (`retribusi`)</p><p>Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\swat1\system\database\DB_driver.php</p><p>Line Number: 330</p>   </div>
```

i make query in model like this:

```
function get_all_retribusi()
  {
    $this->db->select("ID_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI, NAMA_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI, TANGGAL,CONCAT('$', FORMAT(JUMLAH, 2)) as JUMLAH");
    return $this->db->get("retribusi");
  }
```

but, when i try using SQL Query PHPmyadmin i get the data

like:
[image]
anyone can help me?

Comment: `$this->db->select("ID_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI, NAMA_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI, TANGGAL,CONCAT('$', FORMAT(JUMLAH, 2)) as JUMLAH", false);` should do the job

Comment: @Sintakode, not working, only generate numbers without any string Rp, point, and comma...

Comment: yeah of course it is - because your $ sign hast to be a variable or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `ID_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI`, `NAMA_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI`, `TANGGAL`,
       CONCAT('Rp ', FORMAT(JUMLAH, `0))` as JUMLAH
```

has a stray backtick ('`')

I think you want this instead:

```
SELECT `ID_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI`, `NAMA_KATEGORI_RETRIBUSI`, `TANGGAL`,
       CONCAT('Rp ', FORMAT(JUMLAH, `0)) as JUMLAH
```

Turns out there is a codeingiter setting for this:

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
```